# MVC problems. Getting values in Controller from View

Tags: java, swing, model-view-controller

I'm developing the MVC application and don't know how to pass values of textfields in View to Controller, when a user press the button. ActionListener of this button is placed in Controller:

```
private class NewTaskListener implements ActionListener {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        /* here I need to get values of textfields in View
           and pass them to AddNewTaskForUser
        */
        model.AddNewTaskForUser(userName, newTask);
    }
}
```

Listener is added to button in such way:

**Controller:**

```
this.view.AddNewTaskListanaer(new NewTaskListener());
```

**View:**

```
public void AddNewTaskListanaer(ActionListener actionListener)
{
    btnSetupTask.addActionListener(actionListener);
}
```

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: `AddNewTaskListanaer` you're having a typo there

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your view should have public methods:

```
public String getTaskName() {
    return taskName.getText();
}

public String getDescription() {
    return description.getText();
}

// And so on and so on...
```

Now in your controller you can get the desired text field data from the view. So now in your action listener you can do:

```
private class NewTaskListener implements ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        String userName = view.getUsername();
        String newTask = view.getTaskName();

        model.AddNewTaskForUser(userName, newTask);
    }

}
```

This is assuming the action listener class is declared within the controller so it has access to the controllers properties.

Also, methods should not start with a capital letter. They should be in the format `lowerCamelCase`.

Example:

`addActionListener` and `actionPerformed`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass the instances of your textfield to your listener.

```
private class NewTaskListener implements ActionListener {

    private JTextField textField;

    public NewTaskListener(JTextField textField) {
         this.textField = textField;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //.. do stuff
        model.AddNewTaskForUser(userName, newTask);
    }
}
```

and create it like this:

```
this.view.AddNewTaskListanaer(new NewTaskListener(textField));
```

Comment: But I can't do "this.view.AddNewTaskListanaer(new NewTaskListener(textField));" cause this code is in Controller and it doesn't know anything about textField in View